# How do I build a Java project in Eclipse, to create an external JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I recently inherited a large software project written in Java. The last developer used Eclipse, so that's what I'm using, but I can't figure out how to build anything. I don't see any build scripts, and when I open the project in Eclipse the "Build All" and "Build Project" options are greyed out.

The project is essentially a huge collection of packages that depend on one another. I know this has to be a simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer through Googling or through just poking around on Eclipse. I'm very new to this IDE - I have worked with Visual Studio for most of my career. Any questions/suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the 'Build Automatically' checked(under 'Project' menu)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

File -> Export -> Export JAR File. Then select your project, press next twice, select the main class.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you just want to run, open the main class and click the green arrow at the top.

[image]

If you just want to build class files, I believe that Eclipse automatically builds every time you save. You need to select Project -> Build Automatically

[image]

Comment: My answer takes up 3/4 of the page... I don't know if that's a good thing.

Comment: Its a good one though..probably you should have given some Google link, it should definitely be there.

Comment: @sans481 A link to what? There's really not much to cover that the images don't.

Comment: A link explaining build procedure in eclipse.

Comment: @sans481 The best I found with a quick search was http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/building-a-java-project-in-eclipse.html, which is old and kind of useless now.

Comment: I went through these steps and it's saying that there is no Main class. I also tried exporting as a runnable JAR - there were a couple of configurations already set up in the project - but when I do this and open the jar file nothing happens. It's like the program executes and then closes immediately.

Comment: @Jake Did you make sure you set the main class? You'll have to press "Next" twice after selecting the .java files.

Comment: @RyanAmos I tried again and set the main class (there were a couple to choose from), but I'm getting the same error. I'm seeing this error when i do 'java programName.jar' from the command line: 'Error: Could not find or load main class programName.jar'.

Comment: @Jake Use java -jar programName.jar. Also, you don't have to tag me on my response. I automatically get notified.

Comment: Ok, the program is running now. Time to start learning how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Was reading through this (I'm normally at home in NetBeans, just switched to Eclipse because that what we use in class). I followed these instructions, but the file would not load. What I changed to make it work was that instead of selected "JAR" I selected "Runnable JAR" and that worked just fine. Not so many menus to go through either, just had to name the JAR and select the main project. I don't know if this will help anyone in the future, but thanks for putting so much time into your original answer. Quite useful.

Comment: Runnable JAR typically adds in some extra bloat. (some "jarinjar" loader thing... not sure what it's for, but it's there when you do runnable JAR and generate an ANT script) Did you make sure to select a main class in the export JAR menu?

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, Eclipse is always building your project in the background.  That doesn't help you much if what you want is a .jar file or web archive that you can deploy or execute.  The suggestions about export to jar are correct if that's what you want.

It's not clear how much Java experience you have, so I'll just ask this - are you sure there are no build scripts?  Look for files called .pom, or a build.xml or .gradle files.  If the project is as large as you say, I would have to imagine there is some sort of build script/descriptor, but if you're not familiar with Java build systems it may not be obvious to you.

Eclipse (and just about any modern IDE) is a monstrously complex product, and any one or two line description we may give won't come close to getting you up and running on a large codebase.  When you open the project up in eclipse are there red "X" icons on a ton of classes in the source tree?  That's typical if you don't have your libraries all set up, which again, is a big topic.  It would help to know if you imported a project someone already had up (or are just using their old development box) or if you're starting all this from scratch.

Comment: The libraries are all set up, and there are no compilation errors. I was able to export as a jar, but apparently there is no main class definition. I don't know what the entry point is supposed to be. Is this something I need to go figure out from the original developer?

When I try to export as a "Runnable JAR" there are 3 configurations set up, but all three give me the error about missing a 'Main' class.

Comment: So this is something run straight from the console?  At the very least, finding your main method should be easy enough.  Click Search|Java and set the dialog like this to find declarations of a main method in your source code:
[image](http://i.imgur.com/pSywc.png)
(Apparently I can't embed images in comments, so just click on the link.)

Answer (score 4):

you can check the file .project , this file tell eclipse how to build the project.
if there are some code as follow:

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

mean , it's a java project. eclipse will auto build the project in a java project way.
so it don't need another build script.

Answer (score 1):

normally eclipse build automatically as you add new files. try to clean the project first, maybe you will get an ungreyed build option.

do you have java files in the project or just binaries.

Answer (score 1):

File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace.. to include the project into the workspace
After that File -> Export -> Export JAR to export it to a jar file.