# How do I make a JAR file for my homework assignment?

Tags: java, eclipse

My instructor asked us to do a homework assignment in Eclipse and save it as a JAR file so he can open it in his own Eclipse... Previously, I've always zipped my .class files and sent them off, so I don't quite know how to do this...

I did find that I can "export" to a jar file, but when I try to open it again I can't figure out how... so I don't know if I exported it properly or if there's just some unknown method he uses to load it into Eclipse afterward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a Java project in Eclipse, to create an external JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323288/how-do-i-build-a-java-project-in-eclipse-to-create-an-external-jar)

Comment: Why does he need to open JAR file in Eclipse? Maybe he wants to launch it? (Eclipse is not needed then)

Comment: He definitely wants to open it in Eclipse as he said so in class, but I neglected to ask him how we do this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, "export" to JAR file is the way to go. To check what it contains, please understand that a jar file is in fact a zip file with a different extension, and so you can make a copy of the jar file, change its file extension to .zip then unzip it, and you'll see if it contains what you need.

---

**Edit**
I suggest that you use *Export to JAR* (and not *Export to Runnable Jar*) since this has the option of exporting the source files as well.

If you do this, you will see:
[image: Export to JAR]

and you will wish to make the selection *Export to JAR* as noted in the figure.

Next you will see:

[image: Choose Files]

Which is where you choose the files that should be part of the JAR. Make sure to click "Export Java source files and resources" so that your jar file has text readable source. When done, don't click *Finish*, but instead click *Next >*.

Then you will see

[image: Jar Manifest Specification]

The Jar Manifest Specification, where you choose which file that holds the main method, that should be run, by entering it into the Main class: text field, or by finding it using the browse button next to the text field.

Then once you've selected the main file, click Finish:

[image: Finish]

And you're done. Be sure that in the Jar File Specificaion you choose to export the source files.

Comment: The option is called *Export to Runnable JAR file*. There is an *Export to JAR file* as well. I have to say I never tried the latter, but I suppose it doesn't create a Manifest file.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: yes it can create a Manifest but you must specifically tell it which class holds the main method of the jar file. The advantage of the latter, of *Export to JAR* is that it has the option of exporting the source files as well, which I imagine the original poster wishes to do.

Comment: If you are exporting a runnable JAR you need to select a class you want to execute.  Eclipse makes this a little tricky by only showing you "Launch Configurations" that you have after you press "run" at least once on a class with a main method

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Learnt two things: 1) behavior of *Export to JAR* and 2) the spelling of *latter*. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can right click on the project and choose "export as jar"

You could also see the [documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, right click on your project in `Project Explorer`. Then go to export and select `JAR` file. From here you select which files you want to include and a destination for the `JAR` file. Once complete, you can attach this to an email and send to your Professor.

Hope I could help.